# Running LEDs on low voltage for long time

Tags: digital-logic

I've made a series of 4 LEDs connected in parallel. Supply voltage is 12v. Those LEDs are brighter than than I need, so I've connected an 18 ohm resistor in series of each set of 4 LEDs. After connecting the resistor, I got the brightness I wanted and the voltage was 10.8V.

So can I keep this setup for a long time, like for 5-8 hrs continuously? Will those LEDs become dim or unusable after some period of time?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup correctly, can you draw a schematic of it? (there is a schematic tool available in the edit box (shortcut Ctrl-M))

Comment: Yes I'd like to see a schematic too... *"a series of 4 LEDs connected in parallel"* can mean many different things.

Comment: It would be better to connect the LEDs in series than in parallel.

Comment: LEDs are connected I'm series. I have 15 sets (4LEDs + 18ohm resistor in series) connected in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

They will probably last *longer* because they are drawing less current and should run cooler.

[Understanding the Cause of Fading in High-Brightness LEDs](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/feb/understanding-the-cause-of-fading-in-high-brightness-leds)

> The most important factor under the control of the design engineer
>   that does influence longevity is **junction temperature**. Operating the
>   LED according to the manufacturer’s thermal guidelines will reduce the
>   rate of crystal degradation and ensure a long and bright operating
>   life.

Comment: Thank you.  After connecting resistor, LEDs ran cooler than before.

Answer (score 0):

"Will those LEDs become dim or unusable after some period of time?"

The short answer is yes. But only because they will anyway, with the resistors in series they will however last longer than without.

Of course that assumes the resistors are properly rated and installed.  The overall reliability of the thing is reduced since you added more parts and  joints to fail and opportunities for the elements to get in.